# ng-class in Angular js

Tags: angularjs

I need  this html

```
<div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div class="last">4</div>

    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div class="last">8</div>    
<div>
```

I am using this function

```
<div class="col-md-3"
     ng-repeat="items in data.data"
     data-ng-class="{'last': $index%3 == 0 && $index!=0}"  >
```

But i m getting this output

```
<div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div class="last">4</div>

    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div class="last">7</div>
    <div>8</div>

<div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution

```
{'last': ($index+1) % 4 == 0 && $index!=0}
```

@Ben Black comments helped me.

Edit suggested 
 {'last': ($index+1) % 4 == 0 } because $index never be zero 
This solution might help others

Comment: I think that it is ($index+1)

Comment: Correct version will be `ng-class="{'last': ($index+1)%4 == 0}">{{items}}`. `$index!=0` is redundant due to `($index+1)` being always greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

Use `4`, not `3` if you want the rows with index divisible by four.

```
{'last': ($index + 1 ) % 4 == 0 && $index != 0}
```

Comment: $index will start from 0 not from 1

Comment: I think it would need to be $index + 1 (starts at 0)

Comment: @BenBlack: it helps me.. Thanks.. i posted an answer for that